# Что дальше учить новичку PYTHON

Tags: python

закончили основы питона не знаю что дальше учить․ Может надо учить framwork и не угубляца в питоне

Comment: Каким образом вы "закончили основы питона"?

Comment: Попробуйте подучить русский и английский.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогут такие книжки как:

1. Python 3 и PyQt 5. Разработка приложений,
     Прохоренок Н.А. & Дронов В.А.
2. Python Cookbook, 
     David Beazley & Brian K. Jones
3. High Performance Python: Practical Performant Programming for Humans,
     Micha Gorelick & Ian Ozsvald

Также мне очень помог сайт [CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/), на нем можно найти задачи на любой уровень и двигаться дальше